# Javascript equality

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to understand Javascript equality. Can you please tell me why the following line returns `false`?

```
alert((function a(){}) == (function a(){})) // false
```

But as you can see from the following cases `<` returns `false` but `<=` returns `true`, which means `==` should return `true` but it is `false`. Do you have any idea, WHY?

```
alert((function a(){}) < (function a(){})) // false
alert((function a(){}) > (function a(){})) // false
alert((function a(){}) <= (function a(){})) // true
alert((function a(){}) >= (function a(){})) // true
```

Comment: I can't imagine that functions actually have a sensible collation order at all.

Comment: @GregHewgill probably not, but it still doesn't make sense that the last two lines return `true` when the first one returns `false`...

Comment: I think functions have collation order since `function a(){} < "g"` returns `true`.

Comment: Maybe Javascript is converting the function to a string representation (which starts with `function...`) and is comparing the strings in that case.

Comment: I am curious to know, why and where you would need this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are comparing two object using `<` , `<=`, and they are actually compared with string they could covert to.

`"function a(){}" < "function a(){}"` is false.

`"function a(){}" <= "function a(){}"` is true.

***EDIT:***
Why `(function a(){}) == (function a(){})` returns false is because you are compare same type with `==`, so they don't need to covert to string or number to compare, they are two different objects.

Comment: then why `function a(){} == function a(){}` returns `false`

Comment: and I thought I'd never see a good answer to this question... :) +1

Comment: @xdazz, As far as i know this is the rule for `==` comparison. `toPrimitive(x) == toPrimitive(y)` since x and y are object. `toPrimitive` function is basically `toString()`. So they should be equal. Am i wrong?

Comment: @odly No, not for same type. When you use `==` to compare with same type, no conversion is needed.

Answer (score 1):

A little known fact is that Javascript equality operator is actually === not ==. When you run a comparison operator on a function, you are comparing the value of the reference (the location in memory) not the function itself. Since the functions are all separate objects, == will not return true.

From "Javascript - The Definitive Guide" http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch05_04.htm

> On the other hand, objects, arrays, and functions are compared by
>   reference. This means that two variables are equal only if they refer
>   to the same object.

Comment: == only returns true/false on value. === returns true/false if the value/type are the same. Also, when you run an equality operator against the function it is referring to the location in the memory address, which is almost meaningless.

Comment: this is a correct statement which doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I've improved my answer to address this.

Comment: Youy answer didn't explain why `function a(){} == function a(){}` returns false. @xdazz already provided the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

If we test that the functions are not equal, we get true.

```
alert((function a(){}) != (function a(){})) //true
```

This is because each of the functions are a different object and why the equality check returns false.